# How to show missing Console output in latest IntelliJ update

Tags: intellij-idea

I've just updated to IntelliJ 2016.1 and when I run anything (Spring app, or Gradle script) the console output isn't shown anymore -- now I just see the weird Run tree.

[image: Weird Run Tree]

Is there any way of showing the Console output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well that was quick. I found a button to toggle between "Execution Mode" and "Text Mode". It seems execution mode is the default.

Just click the button at the top left of the window.

[image]