# How to view console output in Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea

How to view console output in intellij 2021.2.3 community edition?
I am hitting debug button but the console just shows me the status of gradle tasks.

There is a similar question here ([How to show missing Console output in latest IntelliJ update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36445461/how-to-show-missing-console-output-in-latest-intellij-update)) but the button mentioned does not seem to exist any more in the latest version.
[see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6lTQe.png)

Comment: May you show the screenshot? It should help to select the parent node on the left

Comment: added screenshot

Comment: You are running the App as gradle. To see the console output, you need to run it as Java application. May you show your run config?

Comment: Why should the console not be shown even if I am running the app as gradle?